# Find a first order sentence that characterizes infinite totally ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

[image]

TotOrd is just the axioms of totally ordered sets

I am not sure how to create a sentence that characterizes infinite sets with 2 endpoints

Comment: So, what is your solution for sets *without* endpoints?

Comment: Something is weird. Compactness argument will tell you there is no such $\varphi$. Unless TotOrd means something else than just totally ordered sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such statement: any finite totally ordered set should be a model of $\mathcal{TotOrd} \cup \{\neg \phi\}$, but if theory has finite models of arbitrary large size then it has an infinite model too, so there will be some infinite totally ordered set that $\nvDash \phi$.

Comment: that's really odd... I found this problem in my university's old exam repository